# Is there a way to highlight all text in a bootstrap input field that is using a data input mask on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 and have some input fields that are using a date validation data input mask mask.

If I fill out those date fields, deselect them, then tab back to the fields, the cursor on the browser moves to the end of the date field instead of highlighting the entire field's contents.

Is there anything I can do on focus to highlight the entire field instead of setting the cursor to the end of the field?

```
<input name="EndDate" value="01/31/2020" autocomplete="off" class="form-control date filled valid" data-inputmask="'alias': 'mm/dd/yyyy'" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Coverage End Date must be a date." data-val-original="01/31/2020" data-val-required="IM REQUIRED." id="EndDate" required="required" type="text">
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use the focus function from jQuery `$("#EndDate").focus(function() { $(this).select(); } );` When it is empty it will just put the cursor in the field, but when there is content it will highlight it all.

Comment: Ugh, I'm a noob

Not only does that work, but since all of my fields are input fields, it looks like I can just specify 'input' and it will work for each of my fields, regardless of what type of data input mask they have.

Thanks!

`$('input').click(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });`